# Apps Script summing up Query Data (original data is number) results in concatenation

Tags: google-apps-script, types, sum, concatenation

I came across the following issue when I am trying to work on Query data (data resulting from query function in Google Sheet) using Apps Script:

- Query funtion used: =Query('data source', "select ...sum(..)... where ... group by... pivot...")
- Script used:

```
  var summe = 0;
  for (i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    for (k=0;k<data[i].length;k++){
      summe = summe + data[i][k];
      console.log(...); # to track exactly which column's value becomes text 
      console.log(summe);
    }
```

The results in execution log show that from a certain point it starts to concate text instead of summing up values:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9N35j.png)

Appreciate a lot in advance for any help or ideas out there!!!

Best regards,
Xubo

Comment: I would set a breakpoint and use the debugger to inspect the array "data". My guess is you will find you have some elements that are text not numbers and javacript (app script) is happy to concatenate numbers and strings for you. If you still cannot find it, post a URL for the view only sheet.

Comment: Hey John, thanks a lot for taking time reply! Yes when checking with script it shows some data are strings, but when I check the data in the Google Sheet, they all show as type "1", which is number. It would be so great if we could know why the data from QUERY resulting in so weird issues.

Comment: You are welcome. It is not likely related to QUERY(), even though sheets it looks like a "1", it still may be text. I suggest you check the formatting of those cells. I suspect they are set for plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can avoid this problem by manually converting your data to numbers:

```js
summe = summe + Number(data[i][k]);
```

See [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).

Comment: Thanks a lot Ziga, this solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Zicanotchka's answer. There is a convenient way to keep track the types of your variables:

```js
var a = 1;
var b = "1";
var c = [1];

console.log(a.constructor.name) // Number
console.log(b.constructor.name) // String
console.log(c.constructor.name) // Array
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor

Comment: Hey Yuri, thank you so much for the knowledge sharing! This indeed helps for tacking data type!